# [graph/DFS]: problem about dfs in DAG

Tags: graph-theory, topological-sort

Here is the pseudo-code copied from "intro to algorithm" for your convenience:

```
DFS(G)
1  for each vertex u ∈ V [G]
2       do color[u] ← WHITE   //color changes from WHITE,GRAY,BLACK
3          π[u] ← NIL         //π[u] stands for the parent of vertex u
4  time ← 0
5  for each vertex u ∈ V [G]
6       do if color[u] = WHITE
7             then DFS-VISIT(u)

DFS-VISIT(u)
1  color[u] ← GRAY     ▹White vertex u has just been discovered.
2  time ← time +1
3  d[u] time           //d[u] is the time when u is entered
4  for each v ∈ Adj[u]  ▹Explore edge(u, v).
5       do if color[v] = WHITE
6             then π[v] ← u
7                         DFS-VISIT(v)
8  color[u] BLACK      ▹ Blacken u; it is finished.
9  f [u] ▹ time ← time +1   //f[u] is the time when u is exited
```

Here is my question:
Suppose I got a DAG, its adj-list representation is as follows:

```
1:2, 4
2:5
3:1
4:
5:
```

It should look like this:

```
3 ---> 1 ---> 2 ---> 5
       |---> 4
```

then according to the pseudo-code, π[1] should be NIL, and the same for π[3].
but apparently, π[1] should be 3, right?
Am I missing something?

PS: the reason why I pose the question is that, I was doing the topological sorting using dfs.
And my thought is: 1.find every vertex's parent, namely π[u], 2.check every π[u], if π[u]==0, then u has 0 indegree, and put u in the ordered list.

Answer (score 1):

For computing a topological sort using depth-first search, edges in the DAG point in the direction of dependency (e.g., 1 depends on 3 in your example).

So to do the topological sort you would provide a DAG with edges reversed from the example:

```
1: 3
2: 1
3:
4: 1
5: 2
```

Using this graph, you do the DFS, starting with an empty list for storing the topological sort. After DFS is completed for vertex `v`, `v` is appended to the list. This could be accomplished by adding

```
l ← []
```

after line 4 of `DFS`, where `l` stores the topological sort, and

```
l.append(u)
```

after line 8 of `DFS-VISIT`.

Comment: well, what I don't understand is that, if I start topsort from 1, then according to the pseudo-code, π[1] is nil, and π[1] will remain nil in later topsort (I mean topsort(2,3,4,...)), but in my graph, there is an edge <3,1>, can I say 1's parent should be 3 not nil?

Comment: Your observation is correct that if the second loop in DFS starts with 1, then 2, then 3, and so on, π[1] is nil at the end, with the way the pseudocode is currently written. You could modify the pseudocode to ensure that each vertex with a parent has a non-nil π.

Comment: If your primary goal is to generate the parents list, however, the result is the adjacency list in my answer. That can be computed with a less complicated approach.